# How to customize the login page provided by ABP framework since v3.1

Tags: abp

How to customize the login page provided by the ABP framework v3.1 with the angular template?

Indeed, from Abp v3.1 the Angular UI uses authorization code flow to authenticate the user by redirecting to the MVC UI login page and I don't know how to customize this view.

Comment: Have you seen this article: https://community.abp.io/articles/how-to-customize-the-login-page-for-mvc-razor-page-applications-9a40f3cd

Comment: Thanks for your reply @hikalkan.I saw it but didn't think it was applying for the angular template, my bad. That indeed solved my issue...
Btw, I've been using aspnetboilerplate for many years and now starting a new project using abp.io. You guys are doing great work. Thank you.

Comment: I tried that in `.HttpApi.Host` project. but not working..
https://imgur.com/a/DwfjvWS

Comment: @hikalkan I think this is related to Tag helpers, but not sure how to fix it.